# Best option to showing few entries from database without delay?

Tags: php, mysql

Well basically, if I must show one entry 5000 times per day, what would be the best option to show it each day 5000 times without using too much cpu of server?

So basically, for example we have a database with data (for example 3 entries), and each entry we must show 3000 times per day, what would be the best option?

Would it be cronjobs or any other?

Comment: That would work - run a cronjob to create a text file every night, and then just `include()` that text file instead of the database query. This does fail when the data changes constantly, though.

Comment: would it be safe? Also, would it run faster than just directly including everything from database?

Comment: It's as safe as including any file. And it'll definitely be faster, as you won't need to make a database connection, run a query, and parse the results every time - you do that once, when the system is quiet, and then you're including a static file for the next 24 hours.

Comment: Okay, so basically this is how you ment it -

for example each night at 00:00, it automatically creates a file with these 3 entries ( 3 rows with these words ), and after that for example each (24*60*60)/5000 (17) seconds, we load a script which includes this file in page, correctly?

Comment: Not quite. You create a file with those three entries, formatted correctly. Then, when you need to display that data, instead of doing a database call, you just `include()` your file. Your generator script can run as a cron job, running every night at midnight.

Comment: Yes, but I must retrieve the data from database and display each entry 5000 times per day. My example (as I understood yours), does it, but I'm not sure, with what it does differ from your example. Wouldn't it be so effective?

Comment: is 5000 times a request fixed number or an example? do you need to count up to 5000?

Comment: Does the data actually change over the course of the day?

Comment: Hello, nope they won't change, but I will need to take them from database first time, and yes, the 5000 is maximum per day.

Comment: similar to what @andrewsi points, you can generate a "static" page on each cronjob run (one time a day), so, the webserver has no need to access to the DB

Comment: @LuisSiquot so basically, I should read the data from includes file and display it 5000 times with one cronjob?

Comment: Don't forget that there is a [query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run an `update_script.php` with the cronjob one time a day, that performs one of two posible things:

a) it creates an `included.inc` that is included from other (previously existing) file with `require_once 'included.inc'` (as suggested by @andrewsi) with the data from the DB or

b) it creates an `todaydata.htm` on your public space with the data from the DB

Comment: Okay, so in this example we create the todaydata.htm file which contains 3 words - "word1", "word2", "word3". What would be the best way to show it 5000 times per day on page? Should I somehow load it with ajax, and would it be safe?

Comment: I do not understand you question... todaydata.htm will be created in public space, it will be shown every time it is reached from your clients browser (5000 times or any other number). If you need to use it with ajax it is the same.

Comment: Hello, so basically it creates a new file, which can be viewed as many times as want, correct?

Comment: yes! it is the way. Can I suggest to rename your question to: "Best option to showing few entries from database without delay"??

Comment: done. Accepted also :) also big thanks to Andrewsi.

Answer (score 3):

if you are looking to improve the time taken to retrieve same records few things that you might consider to do :-

1. enable caching at database level as well as application level (like [memcached](http://memcached.org/))
2. figure out the best suitable indexing, so as to make the query fast.

there must be lot of other ways, but these were on top of my mind.

Comment: I vote for [memcached](http://memcached.org/) or the [query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html).

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by creating a mysql job check here

http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

Hope it does what you want.

Comment: Won't be exactly what I ment.